# What version of MATLAB introduced support for Python 3.6?

Tags: python, matlab

MATLAB 2014b introduced the ability to run Python code.  Would someone please tell me what version of MATLAB was the first to support **Python 3.6**?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a thread on the matlab forum, support for python 3.6 was introduced for MATLAB R2017b. Here is the link to the thread: 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/343791-how-do-i-install-matlab-engine-api-for-python3-6?requestedDomain=true

Comment: Forum; you know what I mean.

Comment: Using the wrong name is always confusing, even if some readers may still know what you mean. Better now :-)

Comment: My sincerest apologies :)!